# Reconstruct image from eigenvectors obtained from solving the eigenfunction of Hamiltonian operator in matrix form

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I have an Image ***I***

I am trying to do Automatic Object Extraction using Quantum Mechanics

Each pixel in an image is considered as a potential field, ***V(x,y)***  and hence each wave (eigen) function represents a meaningful region.

2D Time-independent Sschrodinger's equation

[image: 2D Time-independent Schrodinger's Equation]

Multiplying both sides by [image: Transpose of eigenvector]

We get,

[image: equation 3]

Rewriting the Laplacian using Finite Difference approach

[image: laplacian using finite difference approach]

where Ni is the set of neighbours with index i, and |Ni| is the cardinality of, i.e. the number of elements in Ni

Combining the above two equations, we get:

[image: Equation 7]

where **M** is the number of elements in [image: phi]

Now,the left hand side of the equation is a measure of how similar the labels in a neighbourhood are, i.e. a measure of spatial coherence.

Now, for applying this to images, the potential **V** is given as the pixel intensities.

Here, **V** is the pixel intensities

The right hand side is a measure of how close the pixel values in a segment are to a constant value **E**.

Now, the wave functions can be numerically calculated by solving the eigenvectors of Hamiltonian operator in matrix form which is

for ***i*** = ***j***

[image: iequalj]

for [image: jini]

[image: jinNi]

and *elsewhere* **0**

Now, in this paper it is said that first we have to find the maximum and minimum eigenvalues and then calculate the eigenvectors with eigenvalues closest to a number of values regularly selected between the minimum and maximum eigenvalues. the number is 300.

I have calculated the 300 eigenvectors.

And then the absolute square of the eigenvectors are thresholded to obtain the segments.

Fine upto this part.

Now, how do I reconstruct the eigenvectors into a 2D image so as to get the potential segments in the image?

Comment: I do not believe this is a stackoverflow question. This fits more on https://physics.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numerical-methods

Comment: I just gave the mathematical explanation to show where the eigenvectors came from.

Comment: The main thing I want to know is, how to reconstruct the eigenvectors into an image or rather a 2D array. Because, the techniques of reconstructing an image from its eigenvectors obtained in different ways will be different. Isn't it?

Comment: I agree that this is an interesting topic, and I see that this is a question for multiple stacked change sites as you try to combine QM with image analysis and data visualization. But I do not understand why it fits here (unless you can stick a piece of code under it) or identify a languages. Having that said, each eigenvector should be a discretized 2d representation. If you plot the norm per pixel (phi(I,j)) you should have it

Comment: The eigenvectors I obtained are already, normalized. So, can I just reshape the array to a 2D array?

Comment: If you did it correct, then for each eigenvector you should have a value per pixel (your i in the formulation). Just plot this value per pixel.

Comment: Okay, so I did that, but I multiplies the eigenvalues to the eigenvectors after reshaping them into the size of the image. and I get a Image. Thanks for your help.